# Carregar script PHP sem refresh

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

eu estou com um probleminha aqui que acredito que possa ser fácil de resolver, mas estou com dificuldades.

Eu estou com problemas para controlar o acesso à um site que é pago ok, então o usuário faz a assinatura e tem acesso ao site, OK.

O problema é que ele pode passar a senha para um amigo e ambos utilizarão o site, então eu tentei primeiro identificar o IP da máquina mas tive problemas com isso pois o IP acaba mudando em algumas situações não sei o porque (como no celular usando o 3G por exemplo).

Então o que eu fiz foi o seguinte: ao acessar o site eu crio um Token (baseado na funcao date() do php pegando a ano, mes, dia, hora, minuto e segundo do acesso).

Esse Token é salvo no Banco de dados e também salvo no PC do usuario (cookie) e o site sempre verifica antes de abrir qualquer página se o Token salvo no banco de dados é o mesmo do PC (cookie) e caso seja diferente (outra pessoa tentando acessar de outro local) ele bloqueia o acesso precisando 'resetar' o acesso e entrar novamente, ou seja, após 'resetar' o acesso ele vai conseguir entrar, mas somente o 1º que fizer login, pois o outro quando tentar mudar de página o site vai ver que o Token está diferente (já que um novo Token foi gerado) e bloqueia ele... enfim, funciona bem e faz com que a pessoa não passe sua senha já que não conseguirá usar o site ao mesmo tempo com outras pessoas.

Agora eu tenho 1 problema, se a pessoa 1 (titular) acessar o site e abrir um vídeo por exemplo, depois de aberto ela pode avisar a pessoa 2 para fazer login resetando o acesso, mesmo que a pessoa 1 esteja 'irregular' o site só percebe isso quando ela tentar mudar de página, mas se o vídeo tiver 1 hora ela vai assistir tranquilamente até acabar e assim podem fazer esse 'trambique' combinado sem problema para ambos acessarem o conteúdo do site.

O QUE EU QUERO?
Eu tenho um código em PHP que pega o Token salvo no banco e compara com o Token salvo no PC e caso não batam executa um redirecionamento para a página de ERRO devido ao múltiplo login.

Eu queria que essa página (ou script já que é um código pequeno) fosse executada com frequência sem dar refresh, a cada 5 segundos por exemplo, assim quando um segundo usuário fizesse login mesmo que o primeiro ficasse ali paradinho se mudar de página o site ia identificar a falha e derrubá-lo na hora.

Mas como executar um script de PHP dessa forma sem dar refresh na página?

O script que quero executar seria assim:

```html
$sqlToken = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ead WHERE login = '$cpf' AND senha = '$senha'");
 
   while($linhaToken = mysql_fetch_array($sqlToken)){
    $ipToken = $linhaToken['ip'];
    
   }
   
   <!--ATE AQUI EU FIZ A CONEXAO E PEGUEI O IP SALVO NO BANCO-->
   
   $ipCookie = $_COOKIE["tokenAcesso"];

            <!--AQUI EU PEGUEI O IP SALVO NO PC/MOBILE PELO COOKIE-->
      
      if($ipToken != $ipCookie){
            <!--AQUI VEJO SE ESTAO BATENDO-->
      
     <!--SE NAO BATER EU LOJO PARA A PÁGINA DO ERRO-->  
     echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;URL=multiLogin.php'>";
```

Agora eu precisava executar esse script com frequência, a cada 5 segundos mais ou menos para estar sempre verificando se não houve nenhuma irregularidade como outra pessoa logar no site ao mesmo tempo (se isso for feito o Token do banco vai mudar e consequentemente esse pessoa que já estava usando o site vai ser derrubada por esse script pois o Token do seu Cookie vai ser diferente do NOVO TOKEN que foi salvo no banco entenderam?).

Aguardo retorno, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tentou fazer isso via script?

```
<script>
function atualiza(){
var url = 'class/class.php;
 $.get(url, function(dataReturn) {
  $('#id_da_div').html(dataReturn); -> atualiza a div com os dados da class 
 });
}

setInterval("atualiza()",3000); -> chama a função conforme o tempo colocado

</script>
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou exatamente como eu precisava, agora a cada 3 segundos (eu deixei como 3 segundos mesmo pois pra mim está ok) a página verificar e se houve qualquer alteração o usuário é derrubado.